# Data structure able to perform fast and simple updates

Tags: data-structures

Let's say we want to build data structure able to perform two operations.

First one, query is asking for the sum of values in the range $[i, j]$. And the second one, the update is setting all values on the range $[i, j]$ to have value $1$. On the beginning all elements of the array are $0$.

What is the fastest data structure that we can build, not only in terms of big-O, but also in real performance.

Comment: Fenwick trees come to mind.

Comment: As well as interval trees.

Comment: Can you write more how Fenwick trees can be used

Comment: Another trick you might need is lazy propagation.